# Edit URL not being recorded with current script?

Tags: forms, spreadsheet

I currently use a google form to record data into a google spreadsheet. I'd like for the edit URL to be auto enter into a specific column for each row of data created. I currently have the script below and it's executing perfectly however it isn't actually writing the URL to the google spreadsheet and I can't seem to understand why. I've reviewed past material posted however it seems that it's mostly outdated.

```
function assignEditUrls() {
  console.log("dlkjfasdflj;k")
  var form = FormApp.openById('1zZ9vsCIetRkOUL65tvAA9VDkhFFICtKROf1ck14pGsg');

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Matrix');

  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var urlCol = 21; 
  var responses = form.getResponses();
console.log(responses.length)
console.log(responses.map(row => row.getItemResponses()[0].getResponse()))
//   var timestamps = [], urls = [], resultUrls = [];
  
//   for (var i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
//     timestamps.push(responses[i].getTimestamp().setMilliseconds(0));
//     urls.push(responses[i].getEditResponseUrl());
//   }
//   for (var j = 1; j < data.length; j++) {

// console.log(data[j][0])


//     resultUrls.push([data[j][0]?urls[timestamps.indexOf(data[j][0].setMilliseconds(0))]:'']);
//   }
//   sheet.getRange(2, urlCol, resultUrls.length).setValues(resultUrls);  
}
assignEditUrls()
```

It's not writing the Google sheets edit URL to the google spreadsheet.